# React Native:How to wait till a series of setState function to return before executing the next block of code?

Tags: react-native, react-redux

setState in reactnative is asynchronous and I have a series of setState statements in my code and I want the code after these setState statements execute only after all the setState returns

Code

```
 validate = () => {
        this.changedNumber();
        const reg = /^[0]?[789]\d{9}$/;
        if (this.state.spaceName == null || this.state.spaceName =='') {
            this.setState({
                error_spaceName: "Name of space is required",
            })
        } else if (this.state.spaceName.length < 3) {
            this.setState({
                error_spaceName: "Name of space  should be of minimum 3 character length",
            })
        }
        else {
            this.setState({
                error_spaceName: null,
            })

        }
        if (this.state.code === null || this.state.code === '') {
            this.setState({
                error_phone: "Phone Number is required",
            })
        } else if (isValidNumber(Number(this.state.code)) === false) {
            this.setState({
                error_phone: "Contact number should be a Kuwait number",
            })
        }

        else {
            this.setState({
                error_phone: null,
            })

        }



        if (this.state.error == null && this.state.error_spaceName == null && this.state.error_phone == null) {
            this.props.navigation.navigate("LocationScreen")
        }
    }
```

What happnes here is that

```
  if (this.state.error == null && this.state.error_spaceName == null && this.state.error_phone == null) {
        this.props.navigation.navigate("LocationScreen")
    }
```

this part of code gets executed before all the setState returns .I  want to wait till all the setStates returns before checking the conditions? What's the proper way to acheieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You are't able to use was updated state after **setState** in one block , so because you use class components , you are able to use **componentDidUpdate** for solving it :

```js
//...
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
    if (prevState.error != this.state.error
    || prevState.error_spaceName != this.state.error_spaceName
    || prevState.error_phone != this.state.error_phone){
        if (this.state.error == null && this.state.error_spaceName == null && this.state.error_phone == null) {
            this.props.navigation.navigate("LocationScreen")
        }
    }
}
//...
```